# What kind of screw has a wide flange with a smaller head above?

Tags: screws

What is the exact name of this screw type?

[image: screw]

Comment: It looks like the posts/screws we used to use in hanging an old-fashioned wall mount telephone - the kind with cords and all that stuff.

Answer (score 22):

Another name is [keyhole hanger](https://hangmanproducts.com/products/keyhole-hangers-mini):

[image]

Photograph from [Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Hangman-Keyhole-Speaker-Hanging-Screws-6-Pk/20700909).

Comment: This comes closest to a generic industry term. +1

Comment: And here I was, thinking that the keyholes were designed to be used with a not-fully-screwed-in screw.

Comment: @bracco23 I definitely identify with loose screws. When hanging wide objects on wavy walls you can tweak the screws to get things as tight as desired. OTOH, on a flat wall the extra flange on the keyhole hangers should reduce items scuffing the wall.

Answer (score 16):

It is named `bear claw hanger screw` most often on the internet.

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=bear+claw+hanger+screw&iax=images&ia=images

other names found are `double headed screw` and `binding post screw`

Answer (score 10):

Your photo shows one of two similar types of screws.

The type not shown in your photo is consumer-oriented, and searches for "bear claw screw" give lots of examples, as does "double headed screw".

Your photo shows the type used in cabinetry constructed from sheet goods.  The threaded section is short and fat, optimal for gripping in to the face of, say, 3/4" particle board.

[image]

Off-label it can be used how ever one wants. But its small head and short gap (between the head and the flange) make it a poor choice for using it as a hanger bolt for a keyhole slot routed into wood.  Instead, it is designed and dimensioned to mate with a special plate.  The plate is typically mounted into a recess that is routed into the edge of the sheet stock.

If from the US, the one in your photo is likely made by Hafele, who calls it a Modular Screw.  They can also be found on KnappConnectors, who call it a Shoulder Screw for use in there MODULAR product line, or Mod-eez line. If your username 'cern' regards where you work, Knapp is Europe based.  If you are looking for more of the same, make sure you get them from the same supplier as of your plates, otherwise the dimensions might not work out.

Nail, sinker, spike, brad, tack, pin ...? When is a machine threaded fastener a screw? when is it a bolt? Names often differ depending on application, also depending on region/country, and also depending on industry, and also depending on audience, and also depending on field, and also depending on whatever your father called it.

On duckduckgo, the best results come from "modular screw", quoted, in my experience.

We used them extensively in a millwork shop building commercial case work in the early 80's.  We didn't call them anything.

Comment: It would be very helpful (and is actually required by SE rules) if you would [edit] to include the source of your image.

Answer (score 0):

Bear claw hanger screw

aka

Modular Screw, with Wood Screw Thread

[image: hafele]

[hafele](https://www.hafele.com/us/en/product/modular-screw-with-wood-screw-thread/P-00861803/)

Comment: "Modular screw" is a broad category implying two stages of threading, etc. Many composite deck screws could be called "modular", having threads for the decking and framing in distinct sections.  It's not specific enough to describe this particular screw.

Answer (score -3):

1. Looks like aircrete anchor:

[image]

https://www.klium.com/fischer-ftp-k-4-cellenbetonanker-78411-483561

https://www.fischer-international.com/en/products/standard-fixings/plastic-fixings/turbo-aircrete-anchor-ftp-k

---

2. Or a plasterboard anchor:

[image]

https://iponcomp.com/shop/product/fischer-24556-plasterboard-anchor-metall-gkm-100-pcs/1687700

Comment: that screw is all one piece

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Links are not answers (two year from now, those links might no longer work). Each posting should instead be a complete, self-contained answer. Links should be provided only so that people can fact-check and do further research.

Comment: Please don't take the downvotes personally - that's just users disagreeing with the answer.   Don't be discouraged !

Comment: NP. I understand why disagreing. Do not know why there are pictures when i put only links for clarification and to easy future search.

Comment: There are pics because Criggie edited your answer to include them. This saves people the time & effort of clicking a link (which many may not do to a site they're not familiar with) to see what you're talking about. It helps make for a more complete answer.